# Count number of ways to sample $k$ numbers from set without repetition such that the sum of the $k$ numbers is greater than some value

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I've seen many variations of this problem but I can't find a solution for this particular problem.

Let's say I have $N$ consecutive numbers. For example, if $N=100$, ${1, 2, ..., 99, 100}$.

Let's say I generate all the combinations of $N$ choose $k$. I want to know how many of these combinations add up to some value greater than $T$.

When $k=8$ and $N=100$, the number of combinations to generate quickly becomes intractable. But given that the numbers are consecutive, surely there's a way to figure out how many of the combinations add up to a value greater than $T$.

Is there a quick way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(n,k,T)$ be the number of subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ of size $k$ whose sum is $T$ or more. I do not think there is a nice formula for $f(n,k,T)$, but there is a recurrence which allows you to compute it fairly quickly using memoized recursion:
$$
f(n,k,T)=f(n-1,k-1,T-n)+f(n-1,k,T),
$$
with the base cases
$$
f(n,0,T)=1\text{ if $T\le 0$, $0$ otherwise,}\\
f(k,k,T)=1\text{ if $T\le\binom{k+1}2$, $0$ otherwise.}
$$
To prove this, consider separately the number of subsets summing to at least $T$ which contain $n$, counted by $f(n-1,k-1,T-n)$, and those which do not contain $n$, counted by $f(n-1,k,T)$.